# Index was outside the bounds of the array when adding class to list C#

Tags: c#, sql, exception, parallel-processing

Exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

First off, I'm familiar with this exception and I have fixed it before but I'm getting this exception at a very strange line in my code. It is being thrown when I'm adding a user created class to a list of classes in my code. I'm completely lost as to why it is throwing this exception and how to fix it.

```
public static async Task getData()
    {
        // initialize everything
        List<StockData> stockData = new List<StockData>();
        List<StockMarketCompare> stockCompareData = new List<StockMarketCompare>();
        List<StockData> sandpInfo = new List<StockData>();
        List<StockData> sandpDateInfo = new List<StockData>();
        List<StockData> amexList = new List<StockData>();
        List<DateTime> completedDates = new List<DateTime>();
        SymbolInfo symbolClass = new SymbolInfo();
        List<SymbolInfo> ratingSymbols = new List<SymbolInfo>();
        List<StockRating> ratingList = new List<StockRating>();
        bool isGoodToGo = false;
        string symbol, market;
        int activeSymbolsCount = 0;
        int rowCount = 0, completedRowCount = 0;
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        DateTime searchDate = new DateTime();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
        using (SqlCommand sandpCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.DailyGlobalData where Symbol='" + Calculations.sp500 + "'", connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter sandpAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sandpCommand))
        using (DataTable sandpTable = new DataTable("sandp"))
        using (SqlCommand stockRatingsCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.StockRatings", connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter stockRatingsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(stockRatingsCommand))
        using (DataTable stockRatingsTable = new DataTable("stockratings"))
        {
            try
            {
                // fill the sandptable
                sandpAdapter.Fill(sandpTable);

                if (sandpTable != null)
                {
                    var sandpQuery = from c in sandpTable.AsEnumerable()
                                     select new StockData { Close = c.Field<decimal>("Close"), Date = c.Field<DateTime>("Date"), High = c.Field<decimal>("High"), Low = c.Field<decimal>("Low"), Volume = c.Field<Int64>("Volume") };
                    sandpInfo = sandpQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                }

                // fill the stockratingstable
                stockRatingsAdapter.Fill(stockRatingsTable);

                if (stockRatingsTable != null)
                {
                    activeSymbolsCount = stockRatingsTable.Rows.Count;

                    var symbolsAmountQuery = from c in stockRatingsTable.AsEnumerable()
                                             select new SymbolInfo { Symbol = c.Field<string>("Symbol"), Market = c.Field<string>("Market") };
                    ratingSymbols = symbolsAmountQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < activeSymbolsCount; i++)
                {
                    symbol = ratingSymbols.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(i).Symbol;
                    market = ratingSymbols.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(i).Market;
                    ratingList = new List<StockRating>();

                    using (SqlCommand historicalRatingsCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.OldStockRatings where Symbol='" + symbol + "' and Market='" + market + "'", connection))
                    using (SqlDataAdapter historicalRatingsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(historicalRatingsCommand))
                    using (DataTable historicalRatingsTable = new DataTable("historicalratings"))
                    {
                        // fill the historical ratings table
                        historicalRatingsAdapter.Fill(historicalRatingsTable);

                        if (historicalRatingsTable != null)
                        {
                            completedRowCount = historicalRatingsTable.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().Count();
                            completedDates = historicalRatingsTable.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().Select(d => d.Field<DateTime>("Date")).ToList();
                        }
                    }
                            using (SqlCommand amexCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.DailyAmexData where Symbol='" + symbol + "'", connection))
                            using (SqlDataAdapter amexAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(amexCommand))
                            using (DataTable amexTable = new DataTable("amexdata"))
                            {
                                // fill the amex data table
                                amexAdapter.Fill(amexTable);

                                if (amexTable != null)
                                {
                                    var amexFillQuery = from c in amexTable.AsEnumerable()
                                                        select new StockData { Close = c.Field<decimal>("Close"), Date = c.Field<DateTime>("Date"), High = c.Field<decimal>("High"), Low = c.Field<decimal>("Low"), Volume = c.Field<Int64>("Volume") };
                                    amexList = amexFillQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                                    rowCount = amexList.AsParallel().Count();
                                }
                            }

                    Parallel.For(0, rowCount - 30, new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
                    }, async j =>
                    {
                                if (amexList.AsParallel().Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    date = amexList.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(j).Date;
                                    searchDate = date.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(60));

                                    if (completedDates.Contains(date) == false)
                                    {
                                        var amexQuery = from c in sandpInfo
                                                        where c.Date >= searchDate && c.Date <= date
                                                        join d in amexList on c.Date equals d.Date
                                                        select new StockMarketCompare { stockClose = d.Close, marketClose = c.Close };

                                        var amexStockDataQuery = from c in amexList
                                                                 where c.Date >= searchDate && c.Date <= date
                                                                 select new StockData { Close = c.Close, High = c.High, Low = c.Low, Volume = c.Volume, Date = c.Date };

                                        stockCompareData = amexQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                                        stockData = amexStockDataQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                                        isGoodToGo = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        isGoodToGo = false;
                                    }
                                }

                        if (completedDates.Contains(date) == false)
                        {
                            var sandpDateQuery = from c in sandpInfo
                                                 where c.Date >= searchDate && c.Date <= date
                                                 select c;
                            sandpDateInfo = sandpDateQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                            symbolClass = new SymbolInfo() { Symbol = symbol, Market = market };
                            isGoodToGo = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isGoodToGo = false;
                        }

                        if (isGoodToGo)
                        {
                            StockRating rating = performCalculations(symbolClass, date, sandpInfo, stockData, stockCompareData);

                                if (rating != null)
                                {
                                    **ratingList.Add(rating);** // getting the exception thrown here
                                }
                        }
                    });

                    // now save the results to the table outside the parallel for loop

                    ratingList.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
                    List<StockRating> masterList = ratingList.DistinctBy(j => j.date).ToList();
                    saveToTable(masterList, symbol, market);
                    // close the connection
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // close the connection
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Could you reduce this code to the absolute minimum that can reproduce the error?

Comment: @DerekTomes I reduced the code as much as possible so I hope it is better now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`List<T>` is not thread safe and you are calling `.Add` from inside your `Parallel.For`. You either need to lock on the `Add` or use a threadsafe collection in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

This is not your only threading error you have, for example also inside your `Parallel.For` you assign several variables that are all declared in the scope outside of the loop. Your various threads are going to be writing over each other assigning those values.

Comment: This is my first time writing a program using the parallel for loop. So the way to fix this is to declare the variables inside the loop? Thank you very much for the suggestions. Do you have any others?

Comment: You have a whole lot of useless `.AsParallel()` code that is only going to slow your program down, for example you do `amexList.AsParallel().Count()`, `amexList` is a `List<StockData>`, just call `amexList.Count` and it will give you the number, no calculations (parallel or otherwise) required.

Comment: When should I use the AsParallel code then? I was under the impression that it sped up the program

Comment: Parallel code has overhead, when the cost of the overhead is smaller than  the benefit you get from being in parallel that is when you do it. Go read [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) it is a very good introductory e-book by microsoft (For free) that goes over basic concepts like this.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid question but do you have an example on how to properly declare the variable inside the parallel for loop? I'm trying to declare it as a new list inside the loop but then it won't keep the items in the list already

Comment: Please re-read the answers, both answers explain your two options to use a list that persists through the loops but not crash when used by multiple threads.

Comment: Yes I switched to a ConcurrentBag but I misread what you said and I have it all fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`ratingsList` is not thread safe because `List<T>` is not guaranteed to be thread safe (except for static methods), yet you are modifying it from multiple threads.

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>   It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use a [thread safe collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.